# Assigning Score based on Order Sequence in pandas

Tags: pandas

Following are the dataframes I have

**score_df**

```
col1_id col2_id score
1 2 10
5 6 20
```

---

**records_df**

```
date col_id 
D1    6
D2    4
D3    1
D4    2
D5    5
D6    7
```

---

I would like to compute a score based on the following criteria:

When 2 occurs after 1 the score should be assigned 10 or when 1 occurs after 2, score should be assigned 10.

i.e when (1,2) gives a score 10 .. (2,1) also get the same score 10.

considering (1,2) . When 1 occurs first time we dont assign a score. We flag the row and wait for 2 to occur. When 2 occurs in the column we give the score 10.

considering (2,1). When 2 comes first. We assign value 0 and wait for 1 to occur. When 1 occurs, we give the score 10.

So, for the first time - dont assign the score and wait for the corresponding event to occur and then assign the score

So, my result dataframe should look something like this

**result**

```
date col_id score
D1    6     0 -- Eventhough 6 is there in score list, it occured for first time. So 0
D2    4     0 -- 4 is not even there in list
D3    1     0 -- 1 occurred for first time . So 0
D4    2     10 -- 1 occurred previously. 2 occurred now.. we can assign 10. 
D5    5     20 -- 6 occurred previously. we can assign 20
D6    7     0 -- 7 is not in the list
```

I have around 100k rows in both score_df and record_df. Looping and assigning score is taking the time. Can someone help with logic without looping the entire dataframe?

Comment: how is 1 and 2 , 5 and 6 related, can you explain the logic more?

Comment: col1_id, col2_id, col_id are same . Imagine col1_id and col2_id  are two different entities giving a score. i need to map the score in records_df

Comment: In the record_df dataframe, we have the ids.. the score for (1,2) is 10 . It also implies that (2,1) is also 10. In the result dataframe,third row has the colid - 1 . when we encounter 1 , we assign 0 and wait for 2  to occur. In the fourth row colid is 2.. thats why i have assigned the value

Comment: Right , so score for 1 and 2 would be 10 but you have some conditions which says if 1 occurs first time then 0.. etc.. Could you please explain that in the question body to make the example clearer? Thanks

Comment: when (5,6) is 20.. (6,5) is also 20.. In the first row 6 occured. i have given the score 0 and i am waiting for 5 to occur after this. On the fifth row, 5 occured. So i have assigned score 20 to the fifth row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i understand , you can try [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) for unpivotting and then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). keeping the index from the melted df , we check [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) the index is [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) , and then return score from the merge else 0.

```
m = score_df.reset_index().melt(['index','uid','score'],
                              var_name='col_name',value_name='col_id')

final = records_df.merge(m.drop('col_name',1),on=['uid','col_id'],how='left')

c = final.duplicated(['index']) & final['index'].notna()
final = final.drop('index',1).assign(score=lambda x: x['score'].where(c,0))
```

---

```
print(final)

   uid date  col_id  score
0  123   D1       6    0.0
1  123   D2       4    0.0
2  123   D3       1    0.0
3  123   D4       2   10.0
4  123   D5       5   20.0
5  123   D6       7    0.0
```

Comment: final = records_df.merge(m.drop('col_name',1),on=['uid','col_id'],how='left') - records_df doesnt have col_id. it has col1_id and col2_id which are different numbers. How to merge these dataframes after we melt scores_df.

Comment: In your example that is not the case and records df had just 1 column col id. Based on the sample data you have provided, the question is answered really..

Comment: Apologies, i got confused between the names